# MySql union Sum(Case())

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I do a "union" in order to get only distinct values for "ACTIVITY" field, but with the variables started by "OUTPUT_" from "OUTPUT_TAB" appearing in the header. (Like "INPUT_" variables from "INPUT_TAB") .

It's possible ? I can not do it.

Check my Query [PIC_QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i42rg.jpg):

```
SELECT 
  ACTIVIDADE, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATA_VAL_REGISTO = '2017-06-25' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) INPUT_ACT_DATE_VOL, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATA_VAL_REGISTO = '2017-06-24' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PREV_DATE_VOL, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(DATA_VAL_REGISTO,7) = '25' AND YEAR(DATA_VAL_REGISTO) = '2017' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) INPUT_ACT_WEEK_VOL,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(DATA_VAL_REGISTO,7) = '24' AND YEAR(DATA_VAL_REGISTO) = '2017' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) INPUT_PREV_WEEK_VOL, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATA_VAL_REGISTO) = '6' AND YEAR(DATA_VAL_REGISTO) = '2017' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) INPUT_ACT_MONTH_VOL, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATA_VAL_REGISTO) = '5' AND YEAR(DATA_VAL_REGISTO) = '2017' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) INPUT_PREV_MONTH_VOL
FROM INPUT_TAB 
GROUP BY ACTIVIDADE

UNION 

SELECT 
  ACTIVIDADE, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATA_FIM_REP = '2017-06-25' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OUTPUT_ACT_DATE_VOL, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATA_FIM_REP = '2017-06-24' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OUTPUT_PREV_DATE_VOL, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(DATA_FIM_REP,7) = '25' AND YEAR(DATA_FIM_REP) = '2017' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OUTPUT_ACT_WEEK_VOL, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEEK(DATA_FIM_REP,7) = '24' AND YEAR(DATA_FIM_REP) = '2017' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OUTPUT_PREV_WEEK_VOL, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATA_FIM_REP) = '6' AND YEAR(DATA_FIM_REP) = '2017' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OUTPUT_ACT_MONTH_VOL, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DATA_FIM_REP) = '5' AND YEAR(DATA_FIM_REP) = '2017' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OUTPUT_PREV_MONTH_VOL 
FROM OUTPUT_TAB 
GROUP BY ACTIVIDADE
```

RESULT: [PIC_RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSxyV.jpg)

Comment: In case you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a *union* of two query results, but a *join*:

```
SELECT 
  actividade, 
  i.input_act_date_vol, i.input_prev_date_vol, i.input_act_week_vol,
  i.input_prev_week_vol, i.input_act_month_vol, i.input_prev_month_vol,
  o.output_act_date_vol, o.output_prev_date_vol, o.output_act_week_vol, 
  o.output_prev_week_vol, o.output_act_month_vol, o.output_prev_month_vol 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    actividade, 
    SUM(data_val_registo = '2017-06-25') AS input_act_date_vol, 
    SUM(data_val_registo = '2017-06-24') AS input_prev_date_vol, 
    SUM(WEEK(data_val_registo, 7) = 25 AND YEAR(data_val_registo) = 2017) AS input_act_week_vol,
    SUM(WEEK(data_val_registo, 7) = 24 AND YEAR(data_val_registo) = 2017) AS input_prev_week_vol, 
    SUM(MONTH(data_val_registo) = 6 AND YEAR(data_val_registo) = 2017) AS input_act_month_vol, 
    SUM(MONTH(data_val_registo) = 5 AND YEAR(data_val_registo) = 2017) AS input_prev_month_vol
  FROM input_tab
  GROUP BY actividade
) i
JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    actividade, 
    SUM(data_fim_rep = '2017-06-25') AS output_act_date_vol, 
    SUM(data_fim_rep = '2017-06-24') AS output_prev_date_vol, 
    SUM(WEEK(data_fim_rep, 7) = 25 AND YEAR(data_fim_rep) = 2017) AS output_act_week_vol, 
    SUM(WEEK(data_fim_rep, 7) = 24 AND YEAR(data_fim_rep) = 2017) AS output_prev_week_vol, 
    SUM(MONTH(data_fim_rep) = 6 AND YEAR(data_fim_rep) = 2017) AS output_act_month_vol, 
    SUM(MONTH(data_fim_rep) = 5 AND YEAR(data_fim_rep) = 2017) ASoutput_prev_month_vol 
  FROM OUTPUT_TAB 
  GROUP BY actividade
) o USING (actividade);
```

In case there can be input without output or vice versa, you'll have to use an outer join instead. In case there can even be both, input without output and output without input, you'll have to look up how to emulate a full outer join in MySQL.

I've removed `CASE WHEN .. THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`, because a boolean expression results in true or false which equal to 1 and 0 in MySQL.

BTW: As this is all about 2017, you can get your queries simpler and faster by using `WHERE YEAR(data_val_registo)` and `WHERE YEAR(data_fim_rep) = 2017` and removing the condition from the sum expressions.

Comment: Your soluction totaly working on . Thank you very much . 

I thought that i could use the "UNION", and it works, but not the way that i wanted .